# Changing the checkbox with image once the checkbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a project that i need to change the checkbox with image once the user clicked the checkbox. Can anyone help me on how to do this.

as for now, i only have the ability to disable the checkbox once the checkbox is clicked,

```
 $('.cuttingCheckbox').change(function() {
         if (this.checked) {
           this.setAttribute("disabled", true);
            $.post("process_class.php",{
            headmark : this.getAttribute("data-headmark"), 
            headmark_id : this.getAttribute("data-id"),
            columnType : this.getAttribute("data-column")});
         }
       });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace the checkbox with an image you can use the `replaceWith` method.

```
$(this).replaceWith('<img src="' + src + '"/>');
```

If you get the `src` attribute's value from the server, you should cache the element and use the callback function of your `post` request:

```
$('.cuttingCheckbox').change(function() {
     if (this.checked) {
        var _this = this;
        this.disabled = true;
        $.post("process_class.php",{
            headmark    : this.getAttribute("data-headmark"), 
            headmark_id : this.getAttribute("data-id"),
            columnType  : this.getAttribute("data-column")
        }, function(data) {
             $(_this).replaceWith('<img src="' + data.src + '"/>');
        });
     }
});
```

Comment: so by mean by this ?

`$('.cuttingCheckbox').change(function() {
             if (this.checked) {
                $(this).replaceWith('<img src="' + src + '"/>');
                $.post("process_class.php",{
                headmark : this.getAttribute("data-headmark"), 
                headmark_id : this.getAttribute("data-id"),
                columnType : this.getAttribute("data-column")});
             }
           });
`

Comment: @Chriskonz The key point is the `replaceWith` method. The implementation is up to you, since you haven't provided sufficient info about what you are exactly trying to achieve, I have assumed that you want to get the `src` from the server.